# Qml VideoOutput doesn't work after setting source to null once

Tags: qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.8

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property bool flip: true

    Timer {
        interval: 5000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            flip = !flip
            if(flip) {
                videoOutput.source = null
            } else {
                videoOutput.source = player
            }
        }
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: player
    }

    MediaPlayer {
        id: player
        source: "file://video.mp4"
        autoPlay: true
        loops:  MediaPlayer.Infinite
    }
}
```

After a few a trigger of `Timer` that sets `videoOutput.source` to `null`, it will never work again. The `VideoOutput` will just have a stale painting of a previously decoded frame, and will never change.

Comment: Cross posted [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90004/qml-videooutput-doesn-t-work-after-setting-source-to-null-once).

Comment: Thing's I'd try: Does the MediaPlayer's playbackState or status change when the VideoOutput source is set to null?  When you restore the source to player, what happens if you try and prod the player back into life with player.play()?  Can you leave the VideoOutput permanently wired to the MediaPlayer, and achieve what you want by messing with player.source and/or other player parameters?